# What is the kernel of the tensor product of two maps?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, tensor-products, multilinear-algebra

> Assume that $f_1\colon V_1\to W_1, f_2\colon V_2\to W_2$ are $k$-linear maps between $k$-vector spaces (over the same field $k$, but the dimension may be infinity). Then the tensor product $f_1\otimes f_2\colon V_1\otimes V_2\to W_1\otimes W_2$ is defined, and it's obvious that $\ker f_1\otimes V_2+ V_1\otimes \ker f_2 \subseteq \ker (f_1\otimes f_2)$. My question is whether the relation $\subseteq$ is in fact $=$.

If this does not hold, how about assuming all these vector spaces are commutative associated $k$-algebras with identity and that all the maps are $k$-algebra homomorphisms? Or can you give a "right" form of the kernel $\ker (f_1\otimes f_2)$?

Comment: You cannot form the tensor product of two vector spaces unless they are vector spaces over the *same* field. Also, a linear map (or a $K$-homomorphism) of two vector spaces has to commute with the scalars, so it is necessary to assume that $W_i, V_i$ are in fact vector spaces over the same field $K$.

Comment: Of course, I will make it clear now!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Yes, that's true. Let $f_i : V_i \to W_i$ be two linear maps. Since $\mathrm{im}(f_1) \otimes \mathrm{im}(f_2)$ embeds into $W_1 \otimes W_2$, we may assume that $f_1,f_2$ are surjective. But then they are split, so that we can assume that $V_i = W_i \oplus U_i$ and that $f_i$ equals the projection $V_i \to W_i$, with kernel $U_i$. Then $V_1 \otimes V_2 = W_1 \otimes W_2 \oplus W_1 \otimes U_2 \oplus U_1 \otimes W_2 \oplus U_1 \otimes U_2$ and $f_1 \otimes f_2$ equals the projection of $V_1 \otimes V_2$ onto $W_1 \otimes W_2$. Hence the kernel is $W_1 \otimes U_2 \oplus U_1 \otimes W_2 \oplus U_1 \otimes U_2 = U_1 \otimes V_2 + V_1 \otimes U_2$.

This shows even more: The kernel is the pushout $(\ker(f_1) \otimes V_2) \cup_{\ker(f_1) \otimes \ker(f_2)} (V_1 \otimes \ker(f_2))$.

By the way, this argument is purely formal and works in every semisimple abelian $\otimes$-category. What happens when we drop semisimplicity, for example when we consider modules over some commutative ring $R$? Then we only need some [flatness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_module) assumptions:

Let $f_1 : V_1 \to W_1$ and $f_2 : V_2 \to W_2$ be two morphisms in an abelian $\otimes$-category (for example $R$-linear maps between $R$-modules). If $f_1,f_2$ are epimorphisms, then we have exact sequences $\ker(f_1) \to V_1 \to W_1 \to 0$ and $\ker(f_2) \to V_2 \to W_2 \to 0$. Applying the right exactness of the tensor product twice(!), we get that then also

$\ker(f_1) \otimes V_2 \oplus V_1 \otimes \ker(f_2) \to V_1 \otimes V_2 \to W_1 \otimes W_2 \to 0$

is exact. If $f_1,f_2$ are not epi, we can still apply the above to their images and get the exactness of

$\ker(f_1) \otimes V_2 \oplus V_1 \otimes \ker(f_2) \to V_1 \otimes V_2 \to \mathrm{im}(f_1) \otimes \mathrm{im}(f_2) \to 0.$

Now assume that $\mathrm{im}(f_1)$ and $W_2$ are flat. Then $\mathrm{im}(f_1) \otimes \mathrm{im}(f_2)$ embeds into $\mathrm{im}(f_1) \otimes W_2$ which embeds into $W_1 \otimes W_2$. Hence, we have still that the sequence

$\ker(f_1) \otimes V_2 \oplus V_1 \otimes \ker(f_2) \to V_1 \otimes V_2 \to  W_1 \otimes W_2$

is exact. In other words, we have a sum decomposition
$$\ker(f_1 \otimes f_2) = \alpha(\ker(f_1) \otimes V_2) + \beta(V_1 \otimes \ker(f_2)),$$ where $\alpha : \ker(f_1) \otimes V_2 \to V_1 \otimes V_2$ and $\beta : V_1 \otimes \ker(f_2) \to V_1 \otimes V_2$ are the canonical morphisms. In general, these are not monic! However, this is the case, by definition, when $V_1$ and $V_2$ are flat. So in this case we can safely treat $\alpha$ and $\beta$ as inclusions and write $$\ker(f_1 \otimes f_2) = V_1 \otimes \ker(f_2) + \ker(f_1) \otimes V_2.$$

Comment: Thank you very very much! You are so great!

Comment: @Martin Brandenburg:
First of all, a great answer. However, isn't it enough to assume flatness of $W_1$,$W_2$,$im(f_1)$ and $im(f_2)$? The step that $\alpha:ker(f_1) \otimes V_2 \rightarrow V_1 \otimes V_2$ is injective seems to always hold if $W_1$ and $W_2$ are flat (by using the tor-functors). Maybe I've missed something here, but it seems to be the case.

Comment: Can you flesh out a bit what you mean by "applying the right exactness of the tensor product (twice!)"?

Comment: @EricAuld: See Lemma 3.1.20 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1410.1716.pdf for instance (applied to $\mathcal{C}=\mathrm{Vect}(k)$).

Comment: @Martin Brandenburg I'm not familiar with semisimple abelian $\otimes$-categories. I want to know if this is true in the following situation: do we have an exact sequence $(I\otimes A)\oplus(A\otimes I)\to A\otimes A\to A/I\otimes A/I$ for a commutative $k$-algebra and an ideal $I$? I ask this concerning $k$-group schemes and Hopf ideals requiring that $\Delta(I)\subset A \otimes I + I \otimes A$ (see e.g. GTM66, \S 2.1, p. 13), where the author doesn't assume $k$ is a field.

Comment: @EricAuld - by right exactness of $-\otimes V_2$, we have $\ker f_1\otimes V_2\rightarrow V_1\otimes V_2\rightarrow W_1\otimes V_2\rightarrow 0$ exact, in particular the kernel of $V_1\otimes V_2\rightarrow W_1\otimes V_2$ is the image of $\ker f_1\otimes V_2$ in $V_1\otimes V_2$. Meanwhile (by similar logic), right exactness of $W_1\otimes -$ implies the kernel of $W_1\otimes V_2\rightarrow W_1\otimes W_2$ is the image of $W_1\otimes \ker f_2$ in $W_1\otimes V_2$. Now $f_1\otimes f_2$ is the composed map $V_1\otimes V_2 \rightarrow W_1\otimes V_2 \rightarrow W_1\otimes W_2$. Its kernel is the

Comment: preimage of the kernel of the second map along the first map. This is generated by a preimage for every element of the kernel of the second map, plus the kernel of the first map. Now the kernel of the second map we've just shown to be the image of $W_1\otimes \ker f_2$ in $W_1\otimes V_2$. Because $f_1:V_1\rightarrow W_1$ is surjective (remember we are assuming $f_1,f_2$ are epis in this part), the image of $V_1\otimes \ker f_2$ in $V_1\otimes V_2$ finds us at least one preimage for every element in that kernel. So we take these, and add the kernel of the first map, which (we've previously

Comment: shown) is the image of $f_1\otimes V_2$ in $V_1\otimes V_2$. We conclude finally that the kernel of $f_1\otimes f_2:V_1\otimes V_2\rightarrow W_1\otimes W_2$ is the sum in $V_1\otimes V_2$ of the images of $\ker f_1\otimes V_2$ and $V_1\otimes \ker f_2$. Thus, the natural map $\ker f_1\otimes V_2\oplus V_1\otimes \ker f_2\rightarrow V_1\otimes V_2$ surjects onto the kernel of $f_1\otimes f_2$. This gives us the claimed exactness at $V_1\otimes V_2$. Exactness at $W_1\otimes W_2$ follows from the assumption that $f_1,f_2$ are epis. Hope that answers!

Answer (score 1):

## When $f_1$ and $f_2$ are surjective

### Constructing an isomorphism

Suppose first that $f_1$ and $f_2$ are surjective, and that we are working over an arbitrary commutative ring $$.
We may assume that $f_i$ is the canonical quotient map from $V_i$ to $V_i / U_i$ for a submodule $U_i$ of $V_i$.
By abuse of notation, we denote by $U_1 ⊗ V_2 + V_1 ⊗ U_2$ the resulting submodule of $V_1 ⊗ V_2$, even if the homomorphisms from $U_1 ⊗ V_2$ and $V_1 ⊗ U_2$ to $V_1 ⊗ V_2$ are not injective.
The submodule $U_1 ⊗ V_2 + V_1 ⊗ U_2$ of $V_1 ⊗ V_2$ lies in the kernel of $f_1 ⊗ f_2$, whence we get an induced homomorphism of $$-modules
$$
  φ
  \colon 
  (V_1 ⊗ V_2) / (U_1 ⊗ V_2 + V_1 ⊗ U_2)
  \to
  (V_1 / U_1) ⊗ (V_2 / U_2) \,,
  \quad
  [v_1 ⊗ v_2] \mapsto [v_1] ⊗ [v_2] \,.
$$
We want to show that $φ$ is an isomorphism.
This can be done in multiple ways.

1. We can construct an inverse $ψ$ to $φ$ as follows.
   For every element $v_2$ of $V_2$, the composite
   $$
     λ_{v_1}
     \colon
     V_1 \to V_1 ⊗ V_2 \to (V_1 ⊗ V_2) / (U_1 ⊗ V_2 + V_1 ⊗ U_2) \,,
     \quad
     v_1 \mapsto v_1 ⊗ v_2 \mapsto [v_1 ⊗ v_2]
   $$
   is $$-linear and contains $U_2$ in its kernel.
   We get therefore an induced $$-linear map.
   $$
     λ'_{v_1}
     \colon
     V_1 / U_1 \to (V_1 ⊗ V_2) / (U_1 ⊗ V_2 + V_1 ⊗ U_2) \,,
     \quad
     [v_1] \mapsto [v_1 ⊗ v_2] \,.
   $$
   For every element $[v_1]$ of $V / U_1$ we have thus the well-defined map
   $$
     ρ_{[v_1]}
     \colon
     V_2 \to (V_1 ⊗ V_2) / (U_1 ⊗ V_2 + V_1 ⊗ U_2) \,,
     \quad
     v_2 \mapsto λ'_{[v_1]}(v_2) = [v_1 ⊗ v_2] \,.
   $$
   This map is $$-linear and contains $U_2$ in its kernel, and therefore induces a well-defined $$-linear map
   $$
     ρ'_{[v_1]}
     \colon
     V_2 / U_2 \to (V_1 ⊗ V_2) / (U_1 ⊗ V_2 + V_1 ⊗ U_2) \,,
     \quad
     [v_2] \mapsto [v_1 ⊗ v_2] \,.
   $$
   We have altogether a well-defined map
   \begin{align*}
     (V_1 / U_1) × (V_2 / U_2) &\to (V_1 ⊗ V_2) / (U_1 ⊗ V_2 + V_1 ⊗ U_2) \,,
     \\
     ([v_1], [v_2]) &\mapsto ρ'_{[v_1]}([v_2]) = [v_1 ⊗ v_2] \,.
   \end{align*}
   This map is $$-bilinear, and therefore induces the desired $$-linear map
   $$
     ψ
     \colon
     (V_1 / U_1) ⊗ (V_2 / U_2) \to (V_1 ⊗ V_2) / (U_1 ⊗ V_2 + V_1 ⊗ U_2) \,,
     \quad
     [v_1] ⊗ [v_2] \mapsto [v_1 ⊗ v_2] \,.
   $$
2. Let $T$ be another $$-module.
   Any $$-bilinear map from $β$ from $(V_1 / U_1) × (V_2 / U_2)$ to $T$ can be pulled back to a $$-bilinear map from $α$ from $V_1 × V_2$ to $T$, given by $α(v_1, v_2) = β([v_1], [v_2])$.
   This bilinear map $α$ satisfies $α(v_1, v_2) = 0$ whenever $v_1$ is contained in $U_1$ or $v_2$ is contained in $U_2$.

   Suppose conversely that $α$ is any $$-bilinear map from $V_1 × V_2$ to $T$ such that $α(v_1, v_2) = 0$ whenever $v_1$ is contained in $U_1$ or $v_2$ is contained in $U_2$.
   For all $v_1, v'_1 ∈ V_1$ and $v_2, v'_2 ∈ V_2$ with $v_1 - v'_1 ∈ U_1$ and $v_2 - v'_2 ∈ U_2$ we then have
   \begin{align*}
     α(v_1, v_2)
     &=
     α(v'_1 + v_1 - v'_1, v'_2 + v_2 - v'_2)
     \\
     &=
     α(v'_1, v'_2)
     + \underbrace{ α(v'_1, v_2 - v'_2) }_{= 0}
     + \underbrace{ α(v_1 - v'_1, v'_2) }_{= 0}
     + \underbrace{ α(v_1 - v'_1, v_2 - v'_2) }_{= 0}
     \\
     &= α(v'_1, v'_2) \,.
   \end{align*}
   This shows that $α$ descends to a well-defined map $β$ from $(V_1 / U_1) × (V_2 / U_2)$ to $T$, which is then again bilinear.
   (We could also prove this by using the universal properties of $V_1 / U_1$ and $V_2 / U_2$, similar to how we have constructed the inverse $ψ$ before.)
   We have thus constructed an isomorphism
   \begin{align*}
     {}&
     \mathrm{Bilin}(V_1 / U_1 , V_2 / U_2 ;\, T)
     \\
     ≅{}&
     \{
       α ∈ \mathrm{Bilin}(V_1, V_2;\, T)
       \mid
       \text{$α(v_1, v_2) = 0$ whenever $v_1 ∈ U_1$ or $v_2 ∈ U_2$}
     \} \,.
   \end{align*}
   It follows that
   \begin{align*}
     {}&
     \mathrm{Hom}((V_1 / U_1) ⊗ (V_2 / U_2), T)
     \\
     ≅{}&
     \mathrm{Bilin}(V_1 / U_1 , V_2 / U_2 ;\, T)
     \\
     ≅{}&
     \{
       α ∈ \mathrm{Bilin}(V_1, V_2;\, T)
       \mid
       \text{$α(v_1, v_2) = 0$ whenever $v_1 ∈ U_1$ or $v_2 ∈ U_2$}
     \}
     \\
     ≅{}&
     \{
       f ∈ \mathrm{Hom}(V_1 ⊗ V_2, T)
       \mid
       \text{$f(v_1 ⊗ v_2) = 0$ whenever $v_1 ∈ U_1$ or $v_2 ∈ U_2$}
     \}
     \\
     ≅{}&
     \{
       f ∈ \mathrm{Hom}(V_1 ⊗ V_2, T)
       \mid
       \text{$f(x) = 0$ whenever $x ∈ U_1 ⊗ V_2$ or $x ∈ V_1 ⊗ U_2$}
     \}
     \\
     ≅{}&
     \{
       f ∈ \mathrm{Hom}(V_1 ⊗ V_2, T)
       \mid
       \text{$f(x) = 0$ for all $x ∈ U_1 ⊗ V_2 + V_1 ⊗ U_2$}
     \}
     \\
     ≅{}&
     \mathrm{Hom}((V_1 ⊗ V_2) / (U_1 ⊗ V_2 + V_1 ⊗ U_2), T) \,.
   \end{align*}
   By writing out these isomorphisms, we see that it is given (from top to bottom) by the induced homomorphism $φ^*$.
   It follows from Yoneda’s lemma (or more precisely from the fully faithfulness of the Yoneda embedding) that $φ$ is an isomorphism.
3. We could also combine both approaches:
   we use the isomorphism
   \begin{align*}
     {}&
     \mathrm{Hom}((V_1 / U_1) ⊗ (V_2 / U_2), T)
     \\
     ≅{}&
     \{
       α ∈ \mathrm{Bilin}(V_1, V_2;\, T)
       \mid
       \text{$α(v_1, v_2) = 0$ whenever $v_1 ∈ U_1$ or $v_2 ∈ U_2$}
     \}
   \end{align*}
   for $T = (V_1 ⊗ V_2) / (U_1 ⊗ V_1 + V_1 ⊗ U_2)$ to easily construct $ψ$ as the homomorphism corresponding to the bilinear map $(v_1, v_2) \mapsto [v_1 ⊗ v_2]$.

We find in either case that $φ$ is an isomorphism because both $(V_1 ⊗ V_2) / (U_1 ⊗ V_1 + U_2 ⊗ V_1)$ and $(V_1 / U_1) ⊗ (V_2 / U_2)$ have suitable universal properties.

### Diagram chase

We know that tensoring is right exact.
We get therefore the following commutative diagram with exact rows and exact columns:
$$
  \require{AMScd}
  \begin{CD}
    U_1 ⊗ U_2         @>>> V_1 ⊗ U_2         @>>> (V_1 / U_1) ⊗ U_2         @>>> 0 \\
    @VVV                   @VVV                   @VVV                             \\
    U_1 ⊗ V_2         @>>> V_1 ⊗ V_2         @>>> (V_1 / U_1) ⊗ V_2         @>>> 0 \\
    @VVV                   @VVV                   @VVV                             \\
    U_1 ⊗ (V_2 / U_2) @>>> V_1 ⊗ (V_2 / U_2) @>>> (V_1 / U_1) ⊗ (V_2 / U_2) @>>> 0 \\
    @VVV                   @VVV                   @VVV                             \\
    0                 @.   0                 @.   0                         @.
  \end{CD}
$$
So let’s use the following result:

> **Lemma.**
> Let $R$ be a ring and consider the following commutative diagram of $R$-modules with exact rows and exact columns:
> $$
>   \begin{CD}
>     {}   @.    A      @>β>> B      @>>> 0  \\
>     @.         @Vδ'VV       @VVε'V      @. \\
>     C    @>δ>> D      @>ε>> E      @.   {} \\
>     @.         @VVV         @VVγV       @. \\
>     {}   @.    F      @>>>  G      @.   {}
>   \end{CD}
> $$
> The induced sequence $A ⊕ C \xrightarrow{f} D \xrightarrow{g} G$ is again exact.
>
> *Proof.*
> It follows the exactness of the middle row and left column that $g ∘ f = 0$.
> Let $d ∈ \ker(f)$.
> We have $0 = g(d) = γε(d)$, whence $ε(d) ∈ \ker(γ) = \mathrm{im}(ε')$.
> There hence exists $b ∈ B$ with $ε(d) = ε'(b)$.
> By the surjectivity of $β$, there exists $a ∈ A$ with $b = β(a)$.
> Let $d' := d - δ'(a)$.
> We have
> $$
>   ε(d') = ε(d) - εδ'(a) = ε(d) - ε'β(a) = ε(d) - ε'(b) = ε(d) - ε(d) = 0 \,.
> $$
> There hence exists $c ∈ C$ with $d' = δ(c)$.
> We have now $d - δ'(a) = d' = δ(c)$, and therefore $d = δ'(a) + δ(c) = f( (a, c) )$.
> This shows that the kernel of $g$ is contained in the image of $f$.

In our specific example, we find that the sequence
$$
  (U_1 ⊗ V_2) ⊕ (V_1 ⊗ U_2) \to V_1 ⊗ V_2 \to (V_1 / U_1) ⊗ (V_2 / U_2)
$$
is exact.
In other words, the kernel of $V_1 ⊗ V_2 \to (V_1 / U_1) ⊗ (V_2 / U_2)$ is given by $U_1 ⊗ V_2 + V_1 ⊗ U_2$.

## When $f_1$ and $f_2$ are not both surjective

If $f_1$ and $f_2$ are not both surjective then we can proceed as already explained in Martin Brandenburg’s answer:
By using the factorization
$$
  V_1 ⊗ V_2
  \to \mathrm{im}(f_1) ⊗ \mathrm{im}(f_2)
  \to W_1 ⊗ W_2 \,,
$$
we see that the desired equality holds if and only if the homomorphism $\mathrm{im}(f_1) ⊗ \mathrm{im}(f_2) \to W_1 ⊗ W_2$ is injective.
This is, for example, the case if $\mathrm{im}(f_1)$ and $W_2$ are flat, or if $W_1$ and $\mathrm{im}(f_2)$ are flat.
This is in particular the case when $$ is a field, since then every $$-module is free and thus flat.

Answer (score -3):

The isomorphism
$$
\ker (f_1\otimes f_2)=V_1\otimes \ker f_2 + \ker f_1 \otimes V_2
$$
is equivalent to the isomorphism
$$
\operatorname{coker} (f_1\otimes f_2)=\operatorname{coker} f_1\otimes \operatorname{coker} f_2,
$$
since for any ideals $I,J\subset R$ we have
$$
R/(I+J)=R/I\otimes R/J
$$

Comment: This is not a correct argument.