# What is $\ker f \otimes g$?

Tags: modules

I am trying to find out the $\ker(f\otimes g)$ where $f:M \rightarrow P$ and $g:N \rightarrow Q$ are $A$ linear maps where $A$ is not a field. So $(f\otimes g):M\otimes N\rightarrow P\otimes Q $ is $A$ linear map.The question is: can the following inclusion be proper?

$(\ker f\otimes N)\cup(M\otimes \ker g)\subset \ker(f\otimes g) $.

Is there any condition on the modules like flatness (other than vector space case) which forces the reverse containment ?

I am not getting anything,Help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you expect a module to be the union of two submodules, not their sum? Recall that unions of submodules, not contained in each other, are *never* submodules. Or did you mean the union in the correct category, namely modules, and not what 99% of other mathematicians understand by union, namely the union of underlying sets?

Comment: That should not be union ..mistaken

Answer (score 3):

$\ker(f) \otimes N$ doesn't have to be a submodule of $\ker(f \otimes g)$. But there is a canonical homomorphism $\ker(f) \otimes N \to \ker(f \otimes g)$. Similarly, we get a canonical homomorphism on $M \otimes \ker(g)$. Hence, we get a canonical homomorphism $\ker(f) \otimes N \oplus M \otimes \ker(g) \to \ker(f \otimes g)$. This turns out to be surjective *when* $f,g$ are surjective, because of the right exactness of the tensor product.

For more on this, see [What is the kernel of the tensor product of two maps?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/541541/)

Comment: Does the canonical homomorphism come from the tensor product of $ker(f)$ and $N$?

Comment: I don't understand this question. $\ker(f) \otimes N \to M \otimes N$ vanishes when composed with $f \otimes g$, hence factors through $\ker(f \otimes g)$. Does this clear things up?

Comment: Can't understand " ker(f)⊗N→M⊗N vanishes when composed with f⊗g, hence factors through ker(f⊗g)" What I know for a map $f:M\rightarrow P$ if $B \subset Ker(f) $ then $f$ factors through $M/B to P$

Comment: It factors as $\ker(f) \otimes N \to \ker(f \otimes g) \to M \otimes N$.

Comment: The left arrow need not be inclusion

Comment: That's right. See line 1 in my answer.