# Kernel of the tensor product of maps

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

A theorem about the tensor product of modules is that

> If $\varphi: B \to C$ and $\psi: B' \to C'$ are surjective, then 
>   $$\llap{\text{the kernel of} \quad} \varphi \otimes \psi: B \otimes B'
>  \to C \otimes C'$$  $$\llap{\text{is} \qquad}i(\operatorname{ker}
>  \varphi \otimes B') + j(B \otimes \operatorname{ker}\psi),$$ where $i$
>   and $j$ are the tensorings of the inclusions with the other module.

There are a couple of proofs for this. One, given [here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/tensorprod2.pdf#page=8), is to write down the inverse of the map 
$$\frac{B \otimes B'}{i(\operatorname{ker} \varphi \otimes B') + j(B \otimes \operatorname{ker}\psi)} \longrightarrow C \otimes C'.$$

Another way, mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/541554/76333) by Martin Brandenberg, is to note that given two exact sequences
$$A \to B \xrightarrow{\varphi} C \to 0 \rlap{\qquad \text{and}}$$
$$A' \to B' \xrightarrow{\psi} C' \to 0,$$
we can see that the sequence
$$(A \otimes B') \oplus (B \otimes A') \to B \otimes B' \xrightarrow{\varphi \otimes \psi} C \otimes C' \to 0$$
is exact, and we can do so in a purely categorical way.

What troubles me about both these proofs is that, if $\sum b_i \otimes b'_i \overset{\varphi \otimes \psi}{\mapsto} 0 \in C \otimes C'$, I don't see any particular way of writing $\sum b_i \otimes b'_i$ like $i(\operatorname{ker} \varphi \otimes B') + j(B \otimes \operatorname{ker}\psi)$. I feel like there should be a way.

Does anyone have some input on this?

Comment: Definitionally they both contain the sums you are asking for

Comment: @ZelosMalum If you notice, the question is not to prove the theorems or explain why they should be true.

Comment: i did notice it and definitionally the tensor products contains all of the sums of its components