# Coalgebras and Coideals: Why does $\ker(\pi \otimes \mathrm{id}_C ) = I \otimes C$ hold?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, proof-explanation, tensor-products, coalgebras

In a proof on comodules and coideals I found the following passage:

> Let $C$ be a coalgebra, and $I \subset C$ a vector subspace.
>
> Let $\pi \colon C \rightarrow C/I $ be the canonical projection. Consider the linear map $f := (\pi \otimes \mathrm{id}_C) \circ \Delta \colon C \rightarrow C/I \otimes C$.
>
> By the universal property of quotient vector spaces, there is a unique map $F \colon C/I \rightarrow C/I \otimes C$ with $F \circ \pi = f$ if and only if $I \subset \ker(f)$.
> Now $I \subset \ker(f)$ is equivalent to $\Delta(I) \subset \ker(\pi \otimes \mathrm{id}_C) = I \otimes C$, i.e., $I$ is a right coideal.

Why does the last equality $\ker(\pi \otimes \mathrm{id}_C ) = I\otimes C$ hold?

Comment: Well, $\ker(\pi) = I$ and $\ker(\operatorname{id}_C) = {0}$, so the kernel of $\pi \otimes id_C$ is $I \otimes C + C \otimes \{0\} = I \otimes C$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, are you using https://math.stackexchange.com/a/541554/752637?

Comment: I kind of assumed it was true. I should be more careful. That the sum in my previous comment is a subset of the kernel of the tensor product map is clear. But the other inclusion is less clear in general. I think this is what they discuss in the answer you linked to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For every two $$-linear maps
$$
  f_1 \colon V_1 \to W_1 \,,
  \quad
  f_2 \colon V_2 \to W_2
$$
between vector spaces, we have the equality
$$
  \ker(f_1 ⊗ f_2)
  =
  \ker(f_1) ⊗ V_2 + V_1 ⊗ \ker(f_2) \,.
$$
(If $f_1$ and $f_2$ are both surjective, i.e., quotient homomorphisms, then this is also true if we replace $$ by an arbitrary commutative ring.)
Proofs of this can be find in the question [What is the kernel of the tensor product of two maps?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/541541/what-is-the-kernel-of-the-tensor-product-of-two-maps).
It follows in the given situation that
$$
  \ker(π ⊗ \mathrm{id}_C)
  =
  \ker(π) ⊗ C + C ⊗ \ker(\mathrm{id}_C)
  =
  I ⊗ C + C ⊗ 0
  =
  I ⊗ C \,.
$$

Alternatively, we could consider the short exact sequence
$$
  0 \longrightarrow I \longrightarrow C \xrightarrow{\enspace π \enspace} C/I \longrightarrow 0 \,.
$$
Tensoring over $$ is exact because it is a field, whence the sequence
$$
  0
  \longrightarrow I ⊗ C
  \longrightarrow C ⊗ C
  \xrightarrow{\enspace π ⊗ \mathrm{id}_C \enspace} (C/I) ⊗ C
  \to 0
$$
is again exact.
This tells us that $I ⊗ C$ is the kernel of $π ⊗ \mathrm{id}_C$.